# Recyclerview change item color outside adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Currently I'm trying figure out how to change an `RecyclerView` item color outside adapter. I'm just manipulating the position, and works fine! But I must swipe the page to color update, and I don't know what I should do to fix this problem.

Check my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...


        adapter = new viewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        //Add fragments here
        adapter.addFragment(new fragmentList(), ""); //Lista de música
        adapter.addFragment(new fragmentFrequent(), ""); //Frequentes
        adapter.addFragment(new fragmentPlayList(), ""); //Playlist

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        player_prev = findViewById(R.id.prev);
        player_prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if ((currentPos-1) > 0) {
                    killMediaPlayer();
                    initAudio(getApplicationContext(), 
                    RecyclerViewAdapter.mData.get(currentPos - 1).getURL());
                    currentPos -= 1;


                    RecyclerViewAdapter.OldselectedPos = RecyclerViewAdapter.selectedPos;
                    RecyclerViewAdapter.selectedPos = currentPos;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        ...
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
package etes.xdda.music;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener{


    MainActivity activity;
    static List<mList> mData;
    Dialog myDialog;

    public static int selectedPos = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    public static int OldselectedPos = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

    private LinearLayout menu_dialog, menu_dialog2;
    public static TextView song_detail;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity activity, List<mList> mData) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) { }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
        final MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);

        // Dialog ini
        myDialog = new Dialog(activity);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        vHolder.item_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                TextView dialog_name_tv = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name_id);
                TextView dialog_phone_tv = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_author_id);
                ImageView dialog_contact_img = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_img);
                dialog_name_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
                dialog_phone_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone());
                dialog_contact_img.setImageResource(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhoto());

                //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test click "+String.valueOf(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myDialog.show();
            }
        });
        vHolder.menu_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                OldselectedPos = selectedPos;
                selectedPos = vHolder.getAdapterPosition();

                notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
                notifyItemChanged(OldselectedPos);


                menu_dialog = v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.menu_dialog);
                menu_dialog.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);

                menu_dialog2 = v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.menu_dialog2);
                menu_dialog2.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);

                song_detail = v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.song_detail);
                song_detail.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);


                String newName;
                newName = mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName();
                if (newName.length() > 42) {
                    newName = newName.substring(0, 38) + "...";
                }
                song_detail.setText(newName);

                activity.killMediaPlayer();
                activity.initAudio(v.getContext(), mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getURL());
                activity.setMargins(v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id), 0,0,0,205);
                activity.updateNotificationBar("mzPlay", mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
                MainActivity.currentPos =  vHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            }
        });
        return vHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_author.setText(mData.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());

        //Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(holder), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(selectedPos == position){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#373737"));
        }
        else
        {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageButton item_play;
        private LinearLayout menu_play;
        private TextView tv_name;
        private TextView tv_author;
        private ImageView img;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            item_play = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_id);
            menu_play = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_id);

            tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_list);
            tv_author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_list);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_music);
        }
    }
}
```

Video: https://ntcdn.stream/20181009_2342010.mp4

The problem is: I must swipe the page to item colors be updated, how can I update the colors without page swipe?

Comment: What's the porpouse of having a public static MyViewHolder holder; in your adapter? And why your changeColor() method is static?

Comment: To access from MainActivity and update item position color.

Comment: Please instead of "rewriting" entirely your questions, add new information as additions, so the main thread is not obscured and other users can understand the whole question evolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing andoid classes in static variables is really a very bad practice. You should interact with your adapter the regular way, using a non static field, for example:

```
//This will go in your onCreate() for example
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(parameters);
...
adapter.highligtedItemPosition = 10;
adapter.notifyItemChanged(10);
```

and later in your onBindViewHolder() react according to what background you want set:

```
if(position == highligtedItemPosition ){
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#373737"));
}
else{
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
}
```

in this example you must add an integer field:

```
int highligtedItemPosition;
```

to your adapter to store the position of the item you want to change the color of.

**UPDATE:**
You are not calling notifyItemChange() or notifyDataSetChanged() from your activity, so the adapter needs to "wait" for the scrolling action to "see" the changes. You should call notifyItemChange() or notifyDataSetChanged() from your player_prev's OnClickListener instead. So the adapter will reflect the changes immediately.

Comment: I'm not able to call "adapter.notifyItemchanged" inside onCreate(), only notifyDataSetChanged(). Also, I have inserted your code inside a click listener, and I need swipe to update colors, do you know how can I update without swipe?

Comment: What do you mean with swipe to update? If the position you update is visible, the change will occur immediately.

Comment: Hello sir, I've updated thread with new problem and updated the script too. I'll record a video and edit the thread with the link

Comment: Note that, I must swipe up and swipe down the page to refresh item color

Comment: Some people in the world have extremely slow internet connections :) . I'm one of them, so I will appreciate you compress the video to less than 10MB.

Comment: Sir, I'm not able to do it, the quality will reduce considerably and you will not be able to watch

Comment: I'm using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside `player_prev OnClickListener` and nothing is happening :(. The colors is not being updated.

Comment: My mistake, just added right now, and tried again, not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181585/discussion-between-raymond-arteaga-and-karlna).

Comment: Just reviwed what I did, and I've found a little mistake. The updated code from Raymond helped me a lot. Thank you.